# OSX bash minimize window

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command

In the Mac and using the bash shell, I want to execute a file that contains a single command (to start Jupyter Lab) and immediately minimize the terminal window.

Is there a way to do this WITHOUT installing third party software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use [`osascript`](https://ss64.com/osx/osascript.html) and Applescript:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set visible of front window to false'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I do not know what is Applescript is.

Comment: Applescript is all the stuff inside single quotes that Paul has suggested, and you can pass it from `bash` to the Applescript interpreter using the `osascript` command. Just copy the whole line and paste it into your Terminal and press Enter.

Comment: Got it and it works without using Applescript. All I had to do is insert the line that you provided as the first line of the bash command file. This minimizes the screen, and then the second line executes. Perfect. Upvoted!

Comment: The only way to see your window again after you do this is `tell application "Terminal" to set visible of every window to true`. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388051/277466

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52020575/5012644)'s answer, which in my testing appears to make the window fully hidden and unrecoverable, you can use the following to minimise the window to the dock if access is required again later:

```
 osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set miniaturized of every window to true'
```

Comment: Works! However, it minimizes EVERY window, not just the current or front one

Comment: It works to say `front window` instead of `every window`. However, this sends the window down by the trash can instead of back to the dock, so Snap.app can't find  it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file that with the `command` extension, for example `jupiter-lab.command`.

You add execution rights on it (`chmod +x jupiter-lab.command`). You edit the file and insert commands like in a bash script.

For example to open `App Store`, you could insert :

```
open "/Application/App Store.app"
```

The first time you double click on it, you will get a popup that tells you that the command has ended quickly. Just check the `Suppress this message permanently` not to see it anymore.

Note : the terminal will not be minimised but will be closed.

Comment: Your suggestion did not work for me. This is the error that I get:

`The files /Users/main/“jupyter and /Users/main/lab” do not exist.`

The command file that I am using is   
`open "jupyter lab"`

Comment: Note : sorry there was a mistake in my answer that I have just fixed, I had typed `/Library/App Store.app` instead of `/Applications/App Store.app`.

Comment: The application you try to launch in a script ? A binary ? An app ? What is the full path of the binary you want to launch ?

Comment: Script - see my original question. The application is Jupyter (data science IDE) and I invoke it from the bash shell. The full path is not needed. Mark provided a good solution above. Merci bcp.